# TFS 2013 - Merging Word Documents

Tags: visual-studio-2013, merge, docx

I have word documents (.docx) checked into TFS and would like to be able to merge them. This worked great in SVN so I'm perplexed why this won't work in TFS.

In Visual Studio, I have setup the diff and compare tools for word documents to the TortoiseSVN scripts `diff-doc.js` and `merge-doc.js` respectively. The setup looks like the following:

Diff:

- Command: `C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe`
- Arguments: `"C:\path-to-scripts\diff-doc.js" %1 %2 //E:javascript`

Merge:

- Command: `C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe`
- Arguments: `"C:\path-to-scripts\diff-doc.js" %4 %1 %2 %3 //E:javascript`

[image: Visual Studio - Configure User Tools]

In the TFS team collection, I configured the file type *.docx to be mergeable.

However, when it comes time to merge a word document, I only get the options `Take Server Version` and `Keep Local Version`. The option `Merge Changes in Merge Tool` is missing.

Do I need to setup something else to make this possible? Or is it just not possible with TFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for why the option Merge Changes in Merge Tool is missing. This Merge Tool is based on the diff window. Since word file type(.docx) is not supported by this diff window. You can easiy test it. Just compare two word files, will get below error: `One or both of these files are not text files and cannot be opened in the comparison window.` So this file tpye also not supported in the default merge Tool.

If you want to compare or merge this type file, you need to configue comparisonand merge tools per file type (extension) via **Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Visual Studio Team Foundation Server -> Configure User Tools**" button. More details you can refer this question  [MS Office file diff under TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955793/ms-office-file-diff-under-tfs)
[image]

---

Update

This  option 'Merge Changes in Merge Tool' not support when you are using configure tool. It can also be explained since this tool based on the diff window. Unfortunately, you can only use Take Server Version and Keep Local Version or Keep Source Version ,Keep Target version.

Comment: I have already configured this, and it works because I can do diffs. Just not merges.

Comment: I also come to the same result with winmerge tool. Then  this  option 'Merge Changes in Merge Tool' not support when you are using configure tool. It can also be explained since this tool based on the diff window. Unfortunately, you can only use Take Server Version and Keep Local Version or Keep Source Version ,Keep Target version. Have updated my answer.