# Compare word doc in command line without font formats

Tags: javascript, vbscript, ms-word

I just got the [compare word in command line solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606467/open-ms-word-in-compare-document-mode-from-command-prompt).
And try to compare two word file by  [TortoiseSVN diff scripts](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisesvn/source/browse/trunk/contrib/diff-scripts/) (diff-doc.js), but I found it shows to many differences about font or paragraph settings.

Is there any code sample about how to modify the diff-doc.js to ignore font change and ignore paragraph format change?  I just want to focus on the text content at first time.

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% sure what you are asking, but you can do something like this in vbscript:

```
strPath1 = [the location of the first file]
strPath2 = [the location of the second file]
strLog = [the location of a log file]

set ofs =  CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


'create a log file
If Not oFs.FileExists(strLog) Then
    set logFile = oFs.CreateTextFile(strLog, true)
else
set logFile = oFs.openTextFile (strLog, 8, True)
End if

set file1 = ofs.openTextFile (strPath1)
strFile1Buffer = file1.readAll
file1.close

set file2 = ofs.openTextFile (strPath2)

do while not file2.atEndOfStream
    strLine = file2.readLine
    If InStr(strFile1Buffer, strLine) = 0 Then
        strLogEntry = strLogEntry & strLine & vbCrLf
    End If
Loop

file2.Close

strLogEntry = "Lines that are in file1 but not in file2:" & vbCrLf & strLogEntry

logFile.WriteLine strLogEntry
objFile3.Close
```

Check out this:  http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2007/05/24/how-can-i-compare-the-contents-of-two-text-files.aspx

Comment: This is for .txt files. I reread what you asked, "DOC" files. I'll try to adjust my answer.

Comment: Sorry, you are not get my meaning.  Just try diff-doc.js, it works.  I just want it default turn off displaying font modification.

Comment: Oh, then my answer makes no sense.